# I am trying to send text- messages on WhatsApp with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to send text messages on whatsapp web version on chrome.
([www.web.whatsapp.com](http://web.whatsapp.com))

This is the code:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("input")[1].innerHTML="This message was written via JS script! ";

var input = document.getElementsByClassName("icon btn-icon icon-send");
input[0].click();
```

But the problem is , initially when no text is present the input box looks like this:
[image]

And only when I physically write some text it changes to this:

[image]

And only now my script works since it requires the `Send text button`.

I tried Jquery code to simulate keypresses at $('.input)by following function:

```js
function pressKey() {
  var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
  e.which = 32; // # space
  $(".input").trigger(e)[1];
  e.which = 91;
  $(".input").trigger(e)[1];
  e.which = 32; // # space
  $(".input").trigger(e)[1];
  e.which = 32; // # space
  $(".input").trigger(e)[1];

}
```

It didn't work.

How can I get the `Send text` button by script?

[Here is  the screen recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kld1BV1bmg) :

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this snippet, while opening a conversation:

```
function dispatch(target, eventType, char) {
   var evt = document.createEvent("TextEvent");    
   evt.initTextEvent (eventType, true, true, window, char, 0, "en-US");
   target.focus();
   target.dispatchEvent(evt);
}


dispatch(document.querySelector("#compose-input div"), "textInput", "hello!");

function triggerClick() {
  var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });
  document.querySelector(".icon.btn-icon.icon-send").dispatchEvent(event)
}
triggerClick()
```

Comment: It throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null(…) also i think they already changes it cause #compose-input div doesn't exist anymore

Comment: @khalid-lafi what is TextEvent here ?

Answer (score 13):

All options didn't work for me. Thats what I did.

```
function sendMessage(message) {
    var evt = new Event('input', {
        bubbles: true
    });

    var input = document.querySelector("div.input");
    input.innerHTML = message;
    input.dispatchEvent(evt);

    document.querySelector(".icon-send").click();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As Khalid Lafi said, this is the correct script. His code does will return an error when executing

```
dispatch(document.querySelector("#compose-input div"), "textInput", "hello!");
```

This is because you should use "input.div" instead of "#compose-input div". The following script is working for me.

```
function dispatch(target, eventType, char) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("TextEvent");    
    evt.initTextEvent (eventType, true, true, window, char, 0, "en-US");
    target.focus();
    target.dispatchEvent(evt);
}


dispatch(document.querySelector("div.input"), "textInput", "hello!");

function triggerClick() {
var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
  'view': window,
  'bubbles': true,
  'cancelable': true
 });
document.querySelector(".icon.btn-icon.icon-send").dispatchEvent(event);
}

triggerClick();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: does this still work? I am getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null(…)` when I call for `triggerClick`

Answer (score 4):

The following is the updated script. Hope this helps.

```
var input = document.querySelector('.block-compose .input');
setTimeout(function(){
    for(var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        input.innerHTML = "Hello";
        input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles: true}));
        var button = document.querySelector('.block-compose button.icon-send');
        button.click();
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: Still working, only change the selector to '#main [contenteditable~=true]' in input and document.querySelector('button>span[data-icon="send"]').parentElement in button

Comment: I undestand the rest of the code but can you explain what this line do? input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles: true}));

Answer (score 3):

This works in Dec 2019. Original snippet by Shubham modified by Cami Rodriguez (see comments above).

```js
function write_in_chat(text) {
   var input = document.querySelector('#main [contenteditable~=true]');
   setTimeout(() => {       
      input.innerHTML = text;
      input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles: true}));
      var button = document.querySelector('button>span[data-icon="send"]').parentElement;
      button.click();
   }, 500);
}
```

Comment: I undestand the rest of the code but can you explain what this line do? `input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles: true}));`

Comment: https://javascript.info/dispatch-events . Here it is explained.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".input").on("keypress",function(e){ 
 if(e.which == 32 ||  e.which == 13){ alert('msg sent')};

});
```

you have to compare == where as you are assigning =

Comment: check by clicking enter key it will alert you and there should be class="input" for your input box

Comment: Doesn't answer my question. I want to simulate the keystroke affect to get the `send text` button not make a js function to detect keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

Firing an event with a KeyPress into an input will not actually populate the text area because the population is part of the native event.

If your intention is to populate a text field, you'll simply need to set the val. In jQuery this can be done with `.val()`, e.g.:

```
function pressKey() {
  $(".input").val('test');
}
```

The WhatsApp input box probably has an event listener waiting for a keyup event, and if the field is populated, switching it to the send button. If this is the case then you *can* manually trigger an event which will trigger WhatsApp's (non-native) code.

```
function pressKey() {
  $(".input").val('test').trigger($.Event('keyup'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the working script:

```
  function dispatch(target, eventType, char) {
            var evt = document.createEvent("TextEvent");
            evt.initTextEvent (eventType, true, true, window, char, 0, "en-US");
            target.focus();
            target.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }


        dispatch(document.querySelector(".input-container > .input-emoji .input"), "textInput", "hello!");

        function triggerClick() {
            var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
                'view': window,
                'bubbles': true,
                'cancelable': true
            });
            document.querySelector(".icon.btn-icon.icon-send").dispatchEvent(event)
        }
        triggerClick();
```

Comment: TypeError: evt.initTextEvent is not a function

Comment: initTextEvent  --> Does not work with firefox.
Mozilla site states it's not implemented.

Comment: Getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null(…)`