# Send function of WhatsApp Web

Tags: javascript, html, whatsapp

What is the easiest way of hooking into WhatsApp Web with a script and sending a message without clicking on the send button or hitting enter?

Comment: Trying something first and then asking what you did wrong?

Comment: I dont know where to start, that's the problem. I tried using Chrome's Timeline Recording function but I didnt really help me.

Comment: Have you seen [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118268/i-am-trying-to-send-text-messages-on-whatsapp-with-javascript?rq=1)? It seems eerily similar to your own.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it helps me.